# Not show Breadcrumb when put it in Items EXT JS

Tags: extjs, breadcrumbs

I has demo about Breadcrumb, when I using :

```
initComponent: function() {
    var store = new ABC.store.Files();
    this.width = 500;
    this.tbar = [{
        xtype: 'breadcrumb',
        store: store,
        showIcons: true,
        selection: store.getRoot()
    }];

    this.callParent();
}
```

the `Breadscrumb` will be create normally. But when I create it using:

```
items:[{
        xtype: 'breadcrumb',
        store: 'ABC.store.Files',
        showIcons: true,
        selection: 'root'
    }],
renderTo:Ext.getBody()
```

it isn't created. I don't know how ! Can you explain to me about why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your store first:

```
var myStore = new ABC.store.Files();
```

Then, use it in your `items`

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'breadcrumb',
    store: myStore,
    showIcons: true,
    selection: myStore.getRoot()
}],
```

Comment: I was trying to do it using : 
`items:[{

        xtype: 'breadcrumb',

        store: Ext.create('ABC.store.Files'),

        showIcons: true,

        selection: Ext.create('ABC.store.Files').getRoot()

    }],`

It work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could give a hand!